# How to restrict access to ASP NET MVC Controller (On Azure App service) to allow only requests within Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have an Azure App service build on ASP NET Core 3.1, which communication with outside world using websockets.

It has some control interface but it is to be used only within Azure datacenter. Can I restrict specific routes/controllers to be used only within Azure? (for security purpose)

Answer (score 1):

unless you know the ipaddresses or the range, I would say there's no way for that. You would need to use App Service Environment and use an internal lb, this way, only internal traffic would be allowed